# Get magento subtotal from cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm currently using this snippet to show the cart totals in the topcart of my Magento shop. My problem is that it's not always updating when products is put in cart, it's just showing 0$, especially configurable products. But when a second product is put in the cart, it's working again.

Am I missing something, should there be a "check" of some kind before this piece of code?

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal()) ?>
```

Comment: Do you have any extensions that modify behaviour of configurable products? It seems like configurable final price is retrieved from existing child product, but at the first time when it is added, child product is not yet loaded as cart item, so final price is eq to 0.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can also try following code it works for me

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal() ?>
```

Comment: IT seems to work, it's just that configurable products shows 0$ untill I add another product, then both products are showing correctly. It's strange..

Comment: @ThomasNielsen : did you get this to work , im having the same problem the subtotal does not change even if products in cart has been changed , but in my case its not even configurable im just using simple products.

Comment: @Jarus : Yes, it worked well with simple products. Never got it to work fully with configurable products, the "Better Configurable Products" extension dosen't want to add the price correctly.

I use this code: 
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal()) ?>

Comment: I have to give free shipping order over and 1000 and zipcode between 600001 to 600010, i am using webshop matrix rate for shipping method, in this case, shopping cart pricing rule not working free shipping, so i have to plan for do custom PHP code for giving free shipping, My condition how can i give condition like subtotal is equal or greated than 1000 and zipcode 600001 and 600010 in /public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml @ Swapna

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your top cart block is extending a relevant block type such as `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar`.  If you do, you will have access to useful functionality that will save you rewriting unnecessary code.

For example, if you extend `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar` - you can call `getSubtotal()`

An alternative would be to use the following:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
```

Comment: That I will try, even thou' it sounds like some of a job for a newbie.. I'll give it a shot

Comment: I have to give free shipping order over and 1000 and zipcode between 600001 to 600010, i am using webshop matrix rate for shipping method, in this case, shopping cart pricing rule not working free shipping, so i have to plan for do custom PHP code for giving free shipping, My condition how can i give condition like subtotal is equal or greated than 1000 and zipcode 600001 and 600010 in /public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml @ Drew Hunter

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code:

```
$subtotals= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();

echo $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($subtotals , true, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me but I was able to get the subtotal using this:

```
$orderObj = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$orderSubTotal = $orderObj->getSubtotal();
echo $orderSubTotal;
```

This refers to the success.phtml page.

Comment: I am new to PHP, just wnat to know, why you echo $orderSubTotal instead of echo $orderObj?